# Difference in Input shapes for a RL network

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am beginner in DQN and Deep Learning. One of the exercises I am doing has the following network definition.

```
model = Sequential()
# https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/flatten/
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + obs_space))
 
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
 
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
 
model.add(Dense(act_space))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
 
print(model.summary())
```

The Summary for this network is:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 4)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 16)                80        
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 32)                544       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 66        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 2)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 690
Trainable params: 690
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I am trying to create this network using the Functional API like this ..

```
obs_space = env.observation_space.shape
i = Input(shape=obs_space)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(i)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
o = Dense(env.action_space.n, activation='linear')(x)
 
model = Model (i,o)
model.summary()
```

and this gives me this summary ...

```
Model: "model_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         [(None, 4)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 16)                80        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 32)                544       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 66        
=================================================================
Total params: 690
Trainable params: 690
Non-trainable params: 0
```

But this will not work... obviously the inputs shapes are not the same

> Sequential    (None, 4)
> Functional    [(None, 4)]

How could I achieve the Sequential Model shape using the functional API, and what exactly does

```
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + obs_space))
```

do?